# Is it possible to pass input array to another input via jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have some inputs like this:

```
<input name="name1[]" value="1"/>
<input name="name1[]" value="2"/>
<input name="name1[]" value="3"/>
```

and I have another input like this:

```
 <input name="name2" />
```

I want input values of name1 to name2.

I try this:

```
$('input[name=name1]').val($('input[name=name2]').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because there can only be one value per `<input/>`. I haven't tested this but what if you do:

```
$('<input name="name1[]"/>').val($('input[name=name2]').val()).appendTo('form#foo');
```

Essentially, you can create a new `<input/>` with the new value and add it to the form before submitting.

Comment: Why are you using the `appendTo` method?

Comment: Because once you create the input dom object, you have to put it somewhere in the document. Otherwise it won't be any where on the page.

Comment: I didn't notice you are _generating_ an element. But why? It seems the target element _exists_ in the DOM! "and I have another input like this ...". Are you suggesting that he should create a corresponding element for each input? The value of the target element can be comma separated values of `name1[]` group.

Comment: I am not sure if you can have comma separated values in a group. That has never worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want the `<input name="name2" />`  always updated with the values contained in the other inputs.

If this is the case you can do:

```js
$(function () {
  $('input[name^=name1]').on('input', function(e) {
    var txt = $('input[name^=name1]').map(function(index, element) {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join(', ');
    $('input[name="name2"]').val(txt);
  }).first().trigger('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input name="name1[]" value="1"/><br>
    <input name="name1[]" value="2"/><br>
    <input name="name1[]" value="3"/><br>
    <input name="name2" /><br>
</form>
```

If you need the opposite:

```js
$(function () {
  $('input[name="name2"]').on('input', function(e) {
    $('input[name^="name1"]').val(function(index, value) {
      return value + e.target.value;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input name="name1[]" value="1"/><br>
    <input name="name1[]" value="2"/><br>
    <input name="name1[]" value="3"/><br>
    <input name="name2" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` when used with the occurrence of elements would always consider the 1st occurrence. 
In order to extract multiple values from the same set of elements, you would need to use `.val()` with a `function`

Reference : http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function

```
$('input[name=name2]').val(function(index,value)
    {  
      $('input[name="name1[]"]').each(function()
       {
         value += $(this).val();
       });   
       return value;
    });
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/pgyLvx43/